# R - difference scatter plot

Tags: r, plot, scatter

I was wondering if there is a way to subtract two binned scatter plots from one another in R. I have two distributions with the same axes and want to overlay one on top of the other and subtract them hence producing a difference scatter plot.

Here are my two plots:

[image][image]

and my script for the plots:

```
library(hexbin)
library(RColorBrewer)

setwd("/Users/home/")
df <- read.table("data1.txt")
x <-df$c2
y <-df$c3

bin <-hexbin(x,y,xbins=2000)
my_colors=colorRampPalette(rev(brewer.pal(11,'Spectral')))
d <- plot(bin, main=""  , colramp=my_colors, legend=F)
```

Any advice on how to go about this would be very helpful.

**EDIT** 
Found an additional way to do this:

```
xbnds <- range(x1,x2)
ybnds <- range(y1,y2)
bin1 <- hexbin(x1,y1,xbins= 200, xbnds=xbnds,ybnds=ybnds)
bin2 <- hexbin(x2,y2,xbins= 200, xbnds=xbnds,ybnds=ybnds)
erodebin1 <- erode.hexbin(smooth.hexbin(bin1))
erodebin2 <- erode.hexbin(smooth.hexbin(bin2))
hdiffplot(erodebin1, erodebin2)
```

Comment: You have only created one plot. Read examples of constructing simulated data and add code to your quesiton body that produces two datasets that resemble what you are working with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alright, as a starting point, here is some sample data. Each is random, with one shifted to (2,2).

```
df1  <-
  data.frame(
    x = rnorm(1000)
    , y = rnorm(1000)
  )

df2  <-
  data.frame(
    x = rnorm(1000, 2)
    , y = rnorm(1000, 2)
  )
```

To ensure that the bins are identical, it is best to construct one `hexbin` object. To accomplish this, I am using `dplyr`'s `bind_rows` to keep a track of which data.frame the data came from (this would be even easier if you had a single data.frame with a grouping variable).

```
bothDF <-
  bind_rows(A = df1, B = df2, .id = "df")


bothHex <-
  hexbin(x = bothDF$x
         , y = bothDF$y
         , IDs = TRUE
         )
```

Next, we are using a mix of `hexbin` and `dplyr` to count the occurrences of each within each cell. First, apply across the bins, constructing a table (needs to use `factor` to make sure all levels are shown; not needed if your column is already a factor). Then, it simplifies it and constructs a data.frame that is then manipluated with `mutate` to calculate the difference in counts and then joined back to a table that gives the x and y values for each of the id's.

```
counts <-
  hexTapply(bothHex, factor(bothDF$df), table) %>%
  simplify2array %>%
  t %>%
  data.frame() %>%
  mutate(id = as.numeric(row.names(.))
         , diff = A - B) %>%
  left_join(data.frame(id = bothHex@cell, hcell2xy(bothHex)))
```

`head(counts)` gives:

```
  A B  id diff          x         y
1 1 0   7    1 -1.3794467 -3.687014
2 1 0  71    1 -0.8149939 -3.178209
3 1 0  79    1  1.4428172 -3.178209
4 1 0  99    1 -1.5205599 -2.923806
5 2 0 105    2  0.1727985 -2.923806
6 1 0 107    1  0.7372513 -2.923806
```

Finally, we use `ggplot2` to plot the resulting data, as it offers more control (and the ability to more easily use a different variable than count as fills) than `hexbin` itself.

```
counts %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y
             , fill = diff)) +
  geom_hex(stat = "identity") +
  coord_equal() +
  scale_fill_gradient2()
```

[image]

From there, it is easy to play around with axes, colors, etc.